# Maximum determinant with $l_2$ norm penalties

Tags: self-study, likelihood, matrix, determinant

Let the random sample $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n\sim N_p(0,\Sigma)$, then the likelihood is given by,
\begin{align*}
L(\Sigma)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{np/2}|\Sigma|^{n/2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_i Y'_i\Sigma^{-1}Y_i}
\end{align*}
Let $\Sigma^{-1}=\Theta$ and $S=Y'Y$, then the $l_2$ norm penalized likelihood is given by,

\begin{align*}
l_p(\Theta)=\log|\Theta|-tr(S\Theta)-\lambda ||\Theta||_2^2
\end{align*}
where $\lambda$ is the tuning parameter.

So my question is about finding the solution to this problem?  any reference?